# Creating weather forecasting functionality for my discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I've been making a few posts here because coding is still relatively new to me. What I want to do now is to have my bot be able to give me the weather forecast on command. I also want it to be based off of the city rather than zip codes. Ideally, I want it to be able to display the current forecast, max and min temps, humidity, wind speed and cloud cover. However, if that's too complex, I'd be fine with just the current forecast and max and min temps.

I've looked around various places to try and see how to do this, but nothing really seems to work, especially since I am working with other code as well, not primarily weather functions. So, in that case, there's no real code I can provide here, and I don't know where to start. So, perhaps you might know how to make this work, and any pieces of code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would you prefer using an api or some non API source like NPM packages ?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue related to discord.js.

Comment: Yea that should be fine

Comment: You might find it interesting - https://www.npmjs.com/package/weather-js

Comment: @StarsTracker I see what you meant by 'API or non API', but the data would come from an API anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the openweathermap api for that.

https://openweathermap.org/

Read the documention, how to connect the API to your application.
I hope this answer will answer your question.

Comment: Do I choose a specific API option or can I use any?

Comment: Well you can choose any API that you want, but I suggest you this one, because it is the most easiest to use and it has built NPM package with it.